# how can I fill absent points in a series with average of its two neighbor points

Tags: highcharts

I’ve got two series in my chart. I have data coming every day. I register two kinds of information for every data in both  series. There are five points in the first series but four in the second one.  It is vital for both to have a point for every data. I want the absent point in the second series to be filled by the average of its two neighbor points.

Does highstock have any solution for that?

example:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="highstock.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    var $ = jQuery;

    Highcharts.stockChart('chart', {
        chart: {
            panning: false,
        },
        plotOptions:{
            series:{
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['day', [1]]]
                },
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            color:'#23bdbd',
            data: [
                [1558224000000,8197.68969113999992259778082370758056640625],
                [1558310400000,7978.3090724399999089655466377735137939453125],
                [1558396800000,7963.3277791099999376456253230571746826171875],
                [1558483200000,7680.06654589000027044676244258880615234375],
                [1558569600000,7881.846721050000269315205514430999755859375]
            ],
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            color:'#ff5d5d',
            data: [
                [1558224000000,100],
                [1558310400000,150],
                [1558483200000,2300],
                [1558569600000,5500]
            ],
        }],
    });

});
</script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding additional logic in the `load` event callback. Filter the data and find absent points, then add absent points using `series.addPoint()`. Check the code and demo posted below.

**Code:**

```
  chart: {
    panning: false,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const chart = this;
        const absentPoints = chart.series[0].xData.filter(
          data => chart.series[1].xData.indexOf(data) === -1
        );

        absentPoints.forEach(absentPoint => {
          const index = chart.series[0].xData.indexOf(absentPoint);
          const value =
            (chart.series[1].yData[index] +
              chart.series[1].yData[index - 1]) /
            2;

          chart.series[1].addPoint([absentPoint, value], false);
        });

        chart.redraw(false);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/91ntpmyr/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint